# Это СПП? Правильно ли я думаю?

Tags: пунктуация

*Дискутировать с ним было интересно, и я решился-таки присоединиться к ним. :)*

По моему мнению, здесь перед **И** нужна запятая, так как тут две грамматические основы: [дискутировать было интересно] и [я решился присоединиться]. Правильно ли я думаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы совершенно верно думаете и свою мысль аргументируете

Comment: Только предложение ССП, а не СПП.

Comment: Ой, да. Не люблю эти сокращения ССП и СПП. Я знаю, что союз и относится к сочинительным предложениям, а значит, предложение сложносочиненное.